# How to group lines by ID in a file with ID line followed by values lines?

Tags: python, linux, string, dictionary, parsing

The sequence file I generated is as follows:

```
>rpl-7
ATGGCTCCAAC
>rpl-7
AAGAAAGTGCCACAGGTTCCAGAAAC
>rpl-8
AAGAACAAGGAGAAGAAGACCCAATACTTCAAGCGTGC
>rpl-8
GCTCTCCAGATCCTCCGTCTTCGTCAGATCAA
>rpl-8
AAGTTCAACATCATCTGTCTTGAGGA
```

I want to merge the sequences of the same ID, just like that:

```
>rpl-7
ATGGCTCCAAC
AAGAAAGTGCCACAGGTTCCAGAAAC
>rpl-8
AAGAACAAGGAGAAGAAGACCCAATACTTCAAGCGTGC
GCTCTCCAGATCCTCCGTCTTCGTCAGATCAA
AAGTTCAACATCATCTGTCTTGAGGA
```

I use python to judge whether the strings beginning with'>' are the same, and if they are the same, continue to increase the sequence. However, this method cannot output the first ID.In addition, I think it will be easier to use **awk**, unfortunately I am not familiar with awk. Do you know how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate what `rpl` is?

Comment: **rpl** refers to ribosomal protein large subunit.This point is not important, it can be regarded as a unique label.

Comment: Ok my bad i was thinking `>`  are some shell outputs and got confused

Comment: can you tell what exactly it is? Filename or string stored in list etc

Comment: Can you post the code you already have? You can make a Map of id's as key and a list of Strings as value to save the result.

Comment: It is a large string, which is actually part of a file.

Comment: You are right, using a dictionary is a good way, I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping on the input file, grouping to a dictionary with `rpl-id` as key and appending the values to a list:

```
rpl_dict = {}

with open('rpl_input.txt') as rpl_input_file:
    lines = rpl_input_file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        # Fetching current `rpl-id`
        if line.startswith('>rpl'):
            rpl_key = line.strip()
        # Fetching current `rpl-value`
        else:
            rpl_value = line.strip()
            # Appending current `rpl-value`
            if rpl_key not in rpl_dict.keys():
                rpl_dict[rpl_key] = []
            rpl_dict[rpl_key].append(rpl_value)

# {'>rpl-7': ['ATGGCTCCAAC', 'AAGAAAGTGCCACAGGTTCCAGAAAC'], '>rpl-8': ['AAGAACAAGGAGAAGAAGACCCAATACTTCAAGCGTGC', 'GCTCTCCAGATCCTCCGTCTTCGTCAGATCAA', 'AAGTTCAACATCATCTGTCTTGAGGA']}
print(rpl_dict)

with open('rpl_output.txt', 'w') as rpl_output_file:
    for rpl_id, rpl_values in rpl_dict.items():
        rpl_output_file.write(f'{rpl_key}\n')
        for v in rpl_values:
            rpl_output_file.write(f'{v}\n')
```

Output file:

```
>rpl-8
ATGGCTCCAAC
AAGAAAGTGCCACAGGTTCCAGAAAC
>rpl-8
AAGAACAAGGAGAAGAAGACCCAATACTTCAAGCGTGC
GCTCTCCAGATCCTCCGTCTTCGTCAGATCAA
AAGTTCAACATCATCTGTCTTGAGGA
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my previous script did not use dictionary, this method solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do this. Since you mentioned file I have added new line characters you can replace it with the content of your file.

```
import re

regex = r'rpl-\d\n.*(?:$|\n)'
dic = {}
test_str = (">rpl-7\n"
    "ATGGCTCCAAC\n"
    ">rpl-7\n"
    "AAGAAAGTGCCACAGGTTCCAGAAAC\n"
    ">rpl-8\n"
    "AAGAACAAGGAGAAGAAGACCCAATACTTCAAGCGTGC\n"
    ">rpl-8\n"
    "GCTCTCCAGATCCTCCGTCTTCGTCAGATCAA\n"
    ">rpl-8\n"
    "AAGTTCAACATCATCTGTCTTGAGGA\n")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for  match in matches:
    rpl,pro = match.group().split('\n')
    if rpl in dic:
        dic[rpl] = dic[rpl]+pro
    else:
        dic[rpl] = pro
```

**Output:**

```
{'rpl-7': 'ATGGCTCCAACAAGAAAGTGCCACAGGTTCCAGAAAC',
 'rpl-8': 'AAGAACAAGGAGAAGAAGACCCAATACTTCAAGCGTGCGCTCTCCAGATCCTCCGTCTTCGTCAGATCAAAAGTTCAACATCATCTGTCTTGAGGA'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution,

```
input_ = """>rpl-7
ATGGCTCCAAC
>rpl-7
AAGAAAGTGCCACAGGTTCCAGAAAC
>rpl-8
AAGAACAAGGAGAAGAAGACCCAATACTTCAAGCGTGC
>rpl-8
GCTCTCCAGATCCTCCGTCTTCGTCAGATCAA
>rpl-8
AAGTTCAACATCATCTGTCTTGAGGA"""

results = {}

lines = input_.splitlines()
for i, j in zip(lines[::2], lines[1::2]):
    results.setdefault(i, []).append(j)

for i, j in results.items():
    print(i)
    print("\n".join(j))
```

---

```
>rpl-7
ATGGCTCCAAC
AAGAAAGTGCCACAGGTTCCAGAAAC
>rpl-8
AAGAACAAGGAGAAGAAGACCCAATACTTCAAGCGTGC
GCTCTCCAGATCCTCCGTCTTCGTCAGATCAA
AAGTTCAACATCATCTGTCTTGAGGA
```